# ASP MVC return file to browser by reading from sftp

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, filestream, memorystream, ssh.net

i am able to get the file stream from sftp but unable to render that in browser(chrome) ui from controller.

If i store the file in disk and then return its working fine but i want to do that by directly returning the stream not by storing any file

Below is my code

public ActionResult View(string path)
        {

```
        string contentType = "";

        var filePath = Server.MapPath(path);

        switch (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower())
        {
            case ".htm":
            case ".html":
                contentType = "text/HTML";
                break;

            case ".txt":
                contentType = "text/plain";
                break;

            case ".doc":
            case ".rtf":
            case ".docx":
                contentType = "Application/msword";
                break;

            case ".xls":
            case ".xlsx":
                contentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
                break;

            case ".jpg":
            case ".jpeg":
                contentType = "image/jpeg";
                break;

            case ".gif":
                contentType = "image/GIF";
                break;

            case ".png":
                contentType = "image/png";
                break;

            //case ".bmp":
            //    contentType = "image/x-ms-bmp";
            //    break;

            case ".pdf":
                contentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
            case ".bmp":
                contentType = "image/bmp";
                break;
        }

        try
        {

            Stream file = null;

            SftpClient conn = null;


            if (contentType != "")
            {
                conn = GetSFTPConnection();

                conn.Connect();

                file = new MemoryStream();

                if (conn.Exists(path))
                {
                    conn.DownloadFile(path, file);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new SftpPathNotFoundException();
                }

                return File(file, contentType);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new Exception("Unable To Get Requested File");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I havent tested this but I think you will need to send the file to the response, something like replacing:

```
return File(file, contentType);
```

with:

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.BufferOutput = false;
response.OutputStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

And maybe change your action to return a FileResult rather than an ActionResult.

Comment: Works fine . Thank you

Comment: Thanks, could you accept this as the answer please?